# IMacro autoClick on IMG does not go to full url

Tags: image, url, click, imacros

I am using this to autoclick on image in a webpage witch redirects to another url:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:desc_1
WAIT SECONDS=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=ID:i1
```

The url is formated as this: "http://www.example.com/v/?a=l&l=AlphaNumericCode&vl=AlphaNumericCode"

unfortunately the resulting url that is displayed in the new tab page is without the "&vl=AlphaNumeric Code", i.e. only the first part ("http://www.example.com/v/?a=l&l=AlphaNumericCode") is visible in the address bar.

Example(html code):

```
<div style="font-size:11px;color:#888;padding:2px;"id="desc_1">
:::::::::Update Daily :::::::: ::::::::Payment Proofs ::::::&nbsp;
</div>

<div id="da1b" style="display: block; height: 68px;" onclick="clr('1');ul=0">
    <div id="da1d" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;color:#ccc;width:190px;height:68px;vertical-align:middle">
        Click the red dot
    </div>
    <span id="da1c" style="position: absolute; z-index: 9; padding-left: 72px;">
        <a href="http://www.Example.com/v/?a=l&amp;l=E33B0EEC45F2BF7E5294ACA2AC2D712917B2EC3087A3CD8EA25F698333421BE268EED8D388B36093F2C85D0662AD8A25340DA2F1735B2F01ECBC391BBA0B133B&amp;vl=E806723A7D7E3DD2D4FA3C72276FDB26388EF3130661ED70820B0BA781FB3F7FC462ADFB2736AEA7BD66A07DD6FCB59AF3F0629970E687A1" id="l1" target="_blank" onkeydown="return false;" tabindex="-1" onfocus="blur()" oncontextmenu="return false;" onclick="if((ul*1)<10) jQuery.ajax({url: '/v/h/'});">
          <img src="http://img.Example.com/imagens/badge_a1.gif" style="z-index: -99; margin-top: 32px;" id="i1" onclick="gg[1]=1;" height="16" border="0" width="16"></img>
        </a>
    </span>
</div>
```

Result of manual clicking:

http://www.Example.com/v/?a=l&l=E33B0EEC45F2BF7E5294ACA2AC2D712917B2EC3087A3CD8EA25F698333421BE268EED8D388B36093F2C85D0662AD8A25340DA2F1735B2F01ECBC391BBA0B133B&vl=E806723A7D7E3DD2D4FA3C72276FDB26388EF3130661ED70820B0BA781FB3F7FC462ADFB2736AEA7BD66A07DD6FCB59AF3F0629970E687A1

Result of using IMacro:

http://www.Example.com/v/?a=l&l=E33BOEEC45F2BF7E5294ACA2AC2D712917B2EC3O87A3CD8EA25F698333421BE268EED8D388B36O93F2C85DO662AD8A2534O2A2F1735B2FO1ECBC391BBAOB133B

What could be the problem? Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could try to record this click in ‘Experimental event recording mode’. If it doesn’t help, provide html-code of the problem element.

Comment: well, I tried but same code. I'll try to provide html-code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saved your example, recorded and it works on the whole link

```
VERSION BUILD=8920312 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/New%20Text%20Document.html
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=ID:i1
TAB T=2
```

try in FireFox perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code will always work:

```
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:l1 EXTRACT=HREF
TAB OPEN
TAB T=2
URL GOTO={{!EXTRACT}}
```

(Instead of `TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=ID:i1`.)

Comment: Does the code `TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:l1 EXTRACT=HREF` extract a wrong link?